# While using Vertex/Fragment Shader, using glRotatef, glPushMatrix... Problem

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glm-math

I programmed Vertex Shader, Fragment Shader.
I want to use glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix, glRotatef/glTranslatef... But, It's not working.

i make 'class' with Coordinates, Color, Indices.
and I try to draw with vao, vbo, ebo.

*renderScene function

```
void renderScene_sub1(void){
glutSetWindow(subwindow1);

//Clear all pixels
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();


//Let's draw something here

//define the size of point and draw a point.
GLint viewmatLoc = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "viewmat");
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewmatLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, &viewmat[0][0]);



sub1_window.bind_vao();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

glTranslatef(-0.5, -0.5, 0.0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 1, 3 );

//glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sub1_window.get_indices_size(), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glPopMatrix();


//Double buffer
glutSwapBuffers();}
```

*init function

```
void init_sub1(){
//initilize the glew and check the errors.
GLenum res = glewInit();
if (res != GLEW_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s' \n", glewGetErrorString(res));
}

//select the background color
glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0);
glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);



//input vertex
sub1_window.push_vertices(0.5, 0, 0);
sub1_window.push_vcolor(1, 1, 0);

sub1_window.push_vertices(0.5, 0.5, 0);
sub1_window.push_vcolor(0, 1, 1);

sub1_window.push_vertices(0, 0.5, 0.5);
sub1_window.push_vcolor(1, 0, 1);

sub1_window.push_vertices(0, 0, 0.5);
sub1_window.push_vcolor(0, 0, 1);

sub1_window.push_indices(0, 1, 2);
sub1_window.push_indices(2, 3, 0);

programID = LoadShaders("VertexShader.txt", "FragmentShader.txt");

glUseProgram(programID);

sub1_window.gen_vao();
sub1_window.bind_vao();


//vbo
sub1_window.gen_vbo_buffer(2);

sub1_window.bind_vbo_buffer("vertices");
sub1_window.buffer_vbo_data("vertices");

GLint vtxPosition = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vtxPosition");
glVertexAttribPointer(vtxPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, (GLvoid*)(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vtxPosition);


sub1_window.bind_vbo_buffer("vcolor");
sub1_window.buffer_vbo_data("vcolor");

GLint vColor = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "vColor");
glVertexAttribPointer(vColor, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, (GLvoid*)(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

//ebo
sub1_window.gen_ebo();

sub1_window.bind_ebo_buffer();
sub1_window.buffer_ebo_data();

viewmat = glm::rotate(tiltRad * TO_RADIAN, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0, 0)) * glm::rotate(panRad * TO_RADIAN, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0));}
```

Comment: You can not mix the old matrix stack and modern OpenGL. Use matrix uniforms. See [LearnOpenGL - Transformations](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Transformations) and [LearnOpenGL -Camera](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera).

Comment: using uniform is old matrix stack or mordern opengl?
i studied your transformations Link, so i know.
but i want to use glrotationf.
using uniform is make problem? and "using uniform mat VS using glTranslatef" -> what is more often used?

Comment: Actually you can use the old matrices with a new shader program. However, you have to use a version 120 vertex shader. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896103/vertex-fragment-shaders-for-a-opengl-firsrt-person-shooter-view

Comment: @kwangyeonko: Why do you want to use them? They're old, outdated and using them is generally a bad idea. Even back in the days when these function actually were the "proper" interface, most serious programs implemented their own matrix stack and just loaded them using `glLoadMatrix`.

Comment: I see your second link. So, glRotatef/glTranslatef/glScalef/glPushMatrix... is old matrix stack. and using Uniform Variable is modern opengl. It's right? And Using Uniform Matrix is better than glPushMatrix?

Comment: @datenwolf : them means like glPushMatrix?

Comment: old matrix stack has sort of predefined uniforms for matrices that allows to use stuff like `ftransform()` or directly access them from vertex shader however on new core profiles those are undefined so you change the old matrices but your shaders have no access to them instead you pass them by uniforms with your own names and render...  You still can use glRotate on some matrix but in order to pass it to new shaders you have to use for example `float m[16]; glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,m);` and pass the `m` into shaders as `mat4` you can encode your own glRotatef or use lib like GLM too

Comment: @kwangyeonko: `glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix` was one of these "might come in useful" additions to early OpenGL (made over 25 years ago), which turned out to do more harm than good. *Don't use them!* The most direct old-OpenGL equivalent to modern `glUniform` would be `glLoadMatrix`. But again, the old fixed function pipeline has been outdated for over 15 years now, so don't use it at all!

Comment: @kwangyeonko: Yes, you can use matrices supplied by uniforms perfectly fine, without even having to think about glPushMatrix. glPushMatrix has been completely removed from modern OpenGL. The only reason why it doesn't cause an error at compilation is due to the way how operating systems maintain compatibility for old software that was developed 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix, glRotatef/glTranslatef...

Why?

> But, It's not working.

Yes.

> I search in google, and I run example. I dont know why it dosen't apply.

Because those functions are part of the old, outdated, deprecated fixed function pipeline. And unless you're working with legacy OpenGL (or a compatibility profile) **those functions do no longer work**. *So don't use them*.

If the material you're learning from still uses them, or any other part of legacy OpenGL, stop using those materials.

Comment: I studied OpenGL in Univ. In Univ, I learned using Uniform matrix to make model, camera transform. Now, I graduated Univ and soon i join company using opengl next week. Before join company, i want to study more about opengl. In my thought, using uniform matrix is annoying to use it every time. so i want to study about using glpushmatrix. i didn't know legacy opengl and modern opengl.

Comment: Can I use the uniform matrix that I learned before without studying glpushmatrix separately?

Comment: `glPushMatrix` is no longer supported. Nobody uses it anymore. There is zero benefit in using that old stuff. And I really have to applaud your Univ for actually teaching you the modern stuff, because for too long they were behind the times. Among the entry interview questions I'm setting up at my company there's a couple for weeding out those applicants who attempt to use legacy OpenGL. *To put it plain and simple: __Suggesting or showing legacy OpenGL at a job interview may be grounds for not getting the job!__* (it certainly is at the company I co-founded).

Comment: @kwangyeonko: `glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix` are so old, that when `glUniform` was specified nobody did even bother to make any connection there. They are completely pointless in modern code. Again: Do not use them!

Comment: OK. thx. I love u about ur kindness